# Display value from multiple table passed using a ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to display the query result from the controller to view, but I have joined multiple tables in the query.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.detail = (from a in db.table1
                  join b in db.table2 on a.table1_id equals b.table1_id
                   select new{a,b}).SingleOrDefault();
```

**View**
(I'm trying to display like this but fail)

```
@ViewBag.detail.a.table1_column1;
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I think when you join like that the result is an annoymous type object and your ViewBag has no idea what type it is. Can you just select out the value you want (`table1_column1`) and pass that to the ViewBag as just a string, int, datetime or wahtever instead of the whole complex annoymous type object.

Comment: So for example: `var result = (...).SingleOrDefault();`, then for your ViewBag: `ViewBag.detail = result.a.table1_column1;`. If you need all the data then create ViewModel and pass that

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cast to the proper type you want to display.
it's better if you pass a strong type object and then cast the input on a view/partial view like a model.
please refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2010/09/17/best-practices-for-asp-net-mvc/.